# SVG Properties/Presentation attributes and Style-attribute

Tags: css, svg, properties, attributes, specifications

You can declare `Properties/Presentation attributes` in the element:

```
<rect width="50" height="50" fill="blue" />
```

Or you can declare them in the `style`-attribute, if the element supports it:

```
<rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;" />
```

However, some of the elements do not support the `style`-attribute, but they do support some of the `Properties/Presentation attributes`. One example is [Animate](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement)-element.

**Why not all of the elements supporting `Properties/Presentation attributes` do not support the `style`-attribute?**

*I'm using the [SVG 1.1 (Second Edition) – 16 August 2011](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) specification.*

Comment: why you want to style animate ? there is no logic to do so ... animate is meant to add an action not an element

Comment: **The ‘animate’ element is used to animate a single attribute or property over time** ---> so what will be the purpose of style here ? to style what ?

Comment: @Temani Afif: Why would you use any of the multiple `Presentation attributes` the `animate`-element can contain? Why you cannot declare these `properties` inside `style`-attribute? I'm talking about these kind of elements in general, not about `animate` especially.

Comment: because they are not meant to style the element

Comment: `<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" 
         from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />`--> the from is a style ?? no ... the fill of rect is a style ? yes

Comment: when you have an `<img src="" alt="">` can you use alt and src within style ? for sure not because there is no logic for this

Comment: @Temani Afif: Miguel cleared up the problem. The problem is, that not all `properties` are shared between SVG and CSS2. Some are SVG-specific and cannot be declared inside the `style`-attribute.

Comment: and it's exactly what i said in my all my comments if you read them again :) you are talking about property that have nothing to do with styling so there is no logic to put them inside style, even without Specification you can understand this .... even if you forget the SVG, take the img which is a HTML ... img has an alt attribute, is there any logic to use alt inside CSS ? no because it has nothing to do with styling ... same thing like the properties of animate or other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presentation attributes are included in the `animate` element's listing of possible attributes. But if you check the specs [definition of presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermPresentationAttribute) you'll read that:

> Note that although any property may be specified on any element, not
>   all properties will apply to (affect the rendering of) a given
>   element. The definition of each property states to what set of
>   elements it applies.

So if, for example, you check [what elements the `alignment-baseline` applies to](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty), you won't see the `animate` element listed.

In the list of possible presentation attributes for the `animate` element there is also `color-interpolation`, [which does include `animate` between the list of elements that it applies to](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ColorInterpolationProperty). But there's no similar or corresponding CSS property, is there?

Comment: Wow - this goes way deeper than I thought. The 'SVG's styling properties'-section lists the `properties` which are common with between CSS2 and SVG, and the ones that are only SVG specific.
So basically, you can only add properties to `style`-attribute, which are common between CSS2 and SVG ("because the language inside the `style`-attribute is CSS2"). Also some elements, like `Animate`, may contain only SVG-specific `properties`, which means, they cannot be added to `style`-attribute. Because of this, the `animate` doesn't have `style`-attribute, because there would be nothing to be added.